# Science fiction film involving a super-evolved human who is being hunted

Tags: story-identification, movie, soft-sci-fi

I'm having a bad time trying to find a movie, but I remember only some details about it.

There are some (maybe only one) super-evolved human looking beings. I don't remember if they were created from scratch, or if they were evolved humans. They have evolved speed, looks, and everything.
This one evolved human (that I think now is like a programed human) assassinates some people in forest. I think the people were a specially designated group to kill that evolved human.

At the end of the movie a super gigantic robot appears and I think is killed by some missiles.

Comment: When did you watch it? Was it in a theater? On broadcast television? DVD? Streaming service? YouTube? Was the evolved human Caucasian? Black? Asian? Did they look noticeably inhuman? Did the humans hunting him have advanced technology? What language was it is? Did it seem set on Earth? In any particular nation? Was it snowing at any point? Had parts in a desert?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.